# Using Canvas.TextOut in DBGrid - Delphi XE 3

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe3

Please, I need to help with Canvas Use:
When the user moves the mouse over the Title Column of DBGrid,
the title description disappears in Delphi XE 3.
This problem doesn't occurr in delphI 7.

Follow the code below:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses

Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient,
Grids, DBGrids, Types, StdCtrls;

type
TAccessDBGrid = class(TCustomGrid);

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)

DataSource1: TDataSource;
grid1: TDBGrid;
cdsTabela: TClientDataSet;
cdsTabelacodigo_1: TIntegerField;
cdsTabelacodigo_2: TIntegerField;`enter code here`

procedure grid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);

procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);

procedure grid1TitleClick(Column: TColumn);

private
    { Private declarations }
public
    { Public declarations }
end;

var
Form1: TForm1;

implementation
    {$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        cdsTabela.CreateDataSet;
    end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        grid1.Refresh;
    end;

procedure TForm1.grid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var
S1 : string;

begin

with TAccessDBGrid(grid1) do
begin
    RowHeights[0] := 29;
    Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
    case Column.Index of
    0:
    begin
        Column.Title.Caption := '';
        S1 := 'Code';
    end;
    1:
    begin
        Column.Title.Caption := '';
        S1 := 'Description';
    end;
end;

TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Color:= clBlack;
Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, 19, S1);
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.grid1TitleClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
ShowMessage('Title Click! ');
end;

end
```

For more information, see the answer I have posted.

Comment: How do you expect changing row heights after you've already started drawing the row is going to work? I don't have D7 available on this machine, but I don't think that works there either. Set the height of the row in the FormCreate event instead. And why are you hard-coding `19` in the call to `Canvas.TextOut` instead of using an offset from `Rect.Top`? What happens when you change to do so instead of using `19`? And your code makes no sense; you're deleting the Title.Caption on every single row, and drawing the same text from S1 in every cell on every row. This code never worked.

Comment: @KenWhite:  You are quite right to say "this code never worked".  It certainly doesn't work properly in my D7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra information included in the answer you posted makes it far easier to understand what you are trying to do, which is good.  Please try to do that in future questions as it more likely that you will get a better answer faster.

Anyway, I suggest you replace your TDBGrid by Mike Shkolnik's TSMDBGrid.  See:  http://www.scalabium.com/smdbgrid.htm and watch the animation.

His grid includes an `OnDrawColumnTitle` event, which I think will make it far easier to achieve what you want than trying to do it with TDBGrid.  and I gather from your comments that you have followed this suggestion and succeeded in what you were trying to do.

Original answer follows:

I agree with what Ken White has said, but in addition, I think your code
is misconceived.  To see what I mean, try this:

1. Save an IDE Debug layout in which the Code Editor does not overlap with
   your Form1.  The point of doing this is so that Form1 isn't forced to repaint
   which the IDE stos on a breakpoint.
2. Set `DefaultDrawing` to False.  The point of this is that having it set to
   True hides quite how broken your `Grid1DrawColumnCell` is.
3. Put a breakpoint on the first line of your `Grid1DrawColumnCell`, i.e.
   `with TAccessDBGrid(grid1)`.
4. Compile and run.  Notice that the Debugger stops on the breakpoint several
   times while the form is being painted on screen,  but after that it doesn't
   stop on your BP at all.  So, your custom painting never occurs once the form is on-screen, until you cause the grid to refresh e.g. using your form's `OnResize` handler.
5. So what causes the column Title Captions to be blank once you move the mouse
   over the grid.  The answer is, you do!  To see why ...
6. In VCL.DBGrids.Pas, find DrawTitleCell in TCustomDBGrid.DrawCell and put a BP on
   WriteText(Canvas, TextRect, LFrameOffs, LFrameOffs, Caption, Alignment,...
7. Run the app again to the point where your `Grid1DrawColumnCell` has executed
   and the debugger stops on the `WriteText` BP set in step 6.  Evaluate `Caption`
   and you will see that it is empty (because your `Grid1DrawColumnCell` has cleared it, of course).  I suppose you could assign your `S1` value to the column title's Caption before your DrawColumnCell exits, but the drawing it
   does would still be a mess, as you will see if you try e.g.

   ```
   case Column.Index of
   0: begin
   //   Column.Title.Caption := '';
        S1 := 'Code';
        Column.Title.Caption := S1;
   end;
   1: begin
   //   Column.Title.Caption := '';
        S1 := 'Description';
        Column.Title.Caption := S1;
   end;
   ```

QED

So basically you are wasting your time with your `Grid1DrawColumnCell`.  If you
want to know whether it is possible to custom-draw the column headers/titles, and if so, how, 
I suggest you ask a new q, after doing some research.  If you don't find anything, you might consider deriving a TCustomDBGrid descendant and overriding its `DrawCell`; that way you could have better control over the whole drawing process and maybe get closer to whatever it is that you are trying to achieve.

Btw the above is based on the application being compiled in Delphi Seatlle, which is more recent than XE3, but I doubt that makes any difference.

Comment: I added an answer to explain my problem.

Comment: Thank you Martyn, your suggestion to use TSMDBGrid instead of TDBGrid solved my problem and it does much more!
I created one band for 2 columns and now works! Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

The reason I use Canvas.TextOut instead of Title.Caption is
  I need to write 2 rows in Title:

```
        Tests
Test One    Test Two
```

I use "19" instead of Rect.Top because I want to write in Title.
  If I use Rect.Top, the text is drawn in edition area of column

Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, 19, S1);

Follows bellow my real code:

In Grid1DrawColumnCell:

```
with TAccessDBGrid(grid1) do
begin
  RowHeights[0] := 37;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;

  case Column.Index of
  0: begin
       Column.Title.Caption := '';
       S1 := 'Code';
     end;
  1: begin
       Column.Title.Caption := '';
       Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;

       S1 := 'Tests';

       Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
       Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
       Canvas.FillRect(Types.Rect(Rect.Left, 0, Rect.Left + 120, 18));
       Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, 1, S1);
       Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;

       S1 := 'Test One';
     end;
  2: begin
       Column.Title.Caption := '';
       S1 := 'Test Two';
     end;
 end;

  Canvas.Font.Color:= clBlack;
  Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, 19, S1);
end;
```

Comment: Well, it would have helped if you had posted your real code in the first place!

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd simplify the code to you understand it.
But I couldn't.
Please, can you help me yet?